# How to create a function that can add or subtract numbers based on a given parameter? And is that a good practice?

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to Java, and I am trying to play around with Java code. I have two functions, one that adds two integers, and the other subtracts two integers. The only thing different between them is the sign (+ or -). I am considering creating a function to unify addition and subtraction.

For example:

```
public class foo {

    public int add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }

    public int subtract(int x, int y) {
        return x - y;
    }

    // Not intended as actual code but rather to show intention
    private int addOrSubtract(int x, int y, someType sign) {
        return x sign y;
    }
    
    // The objective is to be able to use addOrSubtract like (Not intended as actual code but rather to show intention):
//    public int subtract(int x, int y) {
//        return addOrSubtract(x, y, -);
//    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I create such function (addOrSubtract)?
2. Is that considered a good practice in Java?
3. Assuming we create the function (addOrSubtract) what should it's access modifier be?

Comment: (1) Consider using an `enum` and a `switch` statement. (2) That depends vastly on why you're unifying the two functions. (3) Again, that depends greatly on the use case. If you're just working through the logic, don't worry about access modifiers, as assigning them is going to be heavily contrived anyway. When you start doing actual OOP and encapsulating information, then the difference between public and private will start to make more sense.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Regarding point(2), when would you say it's a good practice, and when would it be a bad one? Further resources to read are also welcome : )

Comment: Ask "is there a reason someone would want to use this extra parameter?". If it's HP for a player in a video game, then there may be a good reason to want to conditionally add or subtract (maybe there's a spell in-game that can backfire sometimes). If it's a bank account, then spending money and depositing money are two fundamentally different operations, so you may consider leaving those functions separate.

Comment: Use 2 different methods with correct meaning is good practice instead of using one method with dumb name `addOrSubtract`. You can find lot of Clean Code tutorials in internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this cleanly using `enum` and `switch`:

```
enum Operation {
        ADD {
            public int op(int x, int y) {
                return x + y;
            }
        },
        SUBTRACT {
            public int op(int x, int y) {
                return x - y;
            }
        };
    
        public abstract int op(int x, int y);
    }
```

Now use a switch statement in your code as:

```
switch(sign) {
    case '+':
        return doOp(Operation.ADD, x, y);
    case '-':
        return doOp(Operation.SUBTRACT, x, y);
    //...
}
```

where `doOp(..)` is:

```
private int doOp(Operation op, int x, int y) {
    return op.op(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Another way is to add the two numbers but if there is a minus, multiply by -1 the second.

Comment: For a school project, yes. For production code, no.